# changed closed error while doing git push

Tags: android, git, repository

I am trying to push some changes to a git project and had to amend some changes to my local commits, so rebased onto a MERGED change 400918 (otherwise it wouldn’t  allow me to set the edit option, not sure if there is any other way) ,made by changes and now when I try push I am running into following error,I even tried to rebase on my changes,its still not working,any inputs here?

```
user{90}> git push ssh://company.com:29418/project HEAD:refs/for/branch                             Counting objects: 43020, done.
Delta compression using up to 32 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4374/4374), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5359/5359), 6.22 MiB | 8.17 MiB/s, done.
Total 5359 (delta 1534), reused 2435 (delta 863)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1534/1534)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://company.com:29418/project
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/branch (change 400918 closed)
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
   $git stash
```

to reset your code to the previous HEAD.

Please take a backup of your code somewhere else because it will undo all the changes since last commit.

After running git stash; your repo will be pointing to previous commit, now you can merge your latest changes in it then push your changes on the server.